# How Android Platform handles application crashes?

Tags: android

Suppose there are lots of applications in android phone. Some of the applications crashed due to some reason. Android will close these crashed applications.I am developing an application which will list out all crashes. One solution is to run logcat command and grep logs for any crashes.

But I want to know if there is any broadcast or intent which is fired when some other application crashes so that I can capture logs for that particular application ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

> One solution is to run logcat command and grep logs for any crashes

Only on Android 4.1 and below, or on a rooted device. You do not have access to logging from other apps otherwise.

> But I want to know if there is any broadcast or intent which is fired when some other application crashes so that I can capture logs for that particular application ?

Not that I am aware of, and certainly none that are documented.